# How to draw shape from path in vue konva?

Tags: vue.js, konvajs

I am trying to use konvajs inside vue. I want to draw an object from path data, but i don't know how to do it. My main purpose is to get the path data from server, but first i would like to see some drawing in action.

Thank you!
All help appreciated.

````
  <div>
    <v-container>
      <v-layout align-end justify-center row fill-height>
        <v-flex xs12>
          <v-stage :config="configKonva">
            <v-layer>
              <v-shape :config="configShape"/>
            </v-layer>
          </v-stage>
        </v-flex>
      </v-layout>
    </v-container>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      configShape: {},
      configKonva: {
        width: 200,
        height: 200
      }
    };
  },
  methods: {},
  mounted() {
    this.configShape = new Konva.Path({
      fill: "#00D2FF",
      stroke: "black",
      strokeWidth: 4,
      data: "m0,0L100,100L0,100L0,0",
      sceneFunc: function(context, shape) {
        // special Konva.js method
        context.fillStrokeShape(shape);
      }
    });
  }
};
</script>```
````

Comment: Why do you want to draw a path as a custom shape?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not recommended to use `sceneFunc` for built-in shapes (such as `Konva.Path`).

Take a look into shapes tutorial for `vue-konva` https://konvajs.org/docs/vue/Shapes.html.

If you want to create a `Konva.Path` you need to use `v-path` component:

```
<v-path
  :config="{
    x: 200,
    fill: '#00D2FF',
    stroke: 'black',
    strokeWidth: 4,
    data: 'm0,0L100,100L0,100L0,0',
  }"
/>
```

Demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/32xxoon18p

You you want to have full control of drawing you can use custom shapes: https://konvajs.org/docs/vue/Custom_Shape.html

Comment: Thank you. I don't know why i didn't see the v-path element..... 
One more question, can i use v-group or something to group elements?

Comment: Yes, you can use all Konva nodes. `v-group` as well.

Answer (score 0):

I could make it work. I don't think, that this is the correct way, but now at least it's working

```
 mounted() {
    this.configShape = new Konva.Path({
      fill: "#00D2FF",
      stroke: "black",
      strokeWidth: 4,
      data: "m0,0L100,100L0,100L0,0",
      sceneFunc: function(context, shape) {
        let arr = shape.attrs.dataArray;

        context.beginPath();
        for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
          if (arr[i].command == "M") {
            context.moveTo(arr[i].points[0],arr[i].points[1]);
          } else if (arr[i].command == "L") {
            context.lineTo(arr[i].points[0],arr[i].points[1]);
          }
        }
        context.closePath();

        // special Konva.js method
        context.fillStrokeShape(shape);
      }
    });
  }
```